# $_GET inside include from URL?

Tags: php, include

i want to include a file, but with `$_get`, i don't know how to explain but i try to give examples.

I need to include a file from URL like this

```
mysite.com/?=MYINCLUDETEXT
```

and to write on `<?php include('MYINCLUDETEXT.php'); ?>`

Anyone tell me, Thank You.

Comment: Please don't do this. It risks letting someone include random files from your website, ones that you might not necessarily want including.

Comment: No i dont need to upload the files, just to tell the Include what to put, if there is a page with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

This will actually do what you want

```
if (isset($_GET['file'])){
  include($_GET['file'].'.php');
}
```

You might also want to test that the file, you are trying to include exists
[file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)  and actually is a file [is_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) and not a folder.

But you have to understand, that even doing this you **are creating a BIG breach in your system** and helping people who want to hack your.
Not only it becomes easier to include uploaded files, (not only files which were validly uploaded), but it also allows to include random files from your server.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems described in answer above - put all your files names (which should be included) in array, like:

```
$pages_array=('home','services','contact').
```

And then check GET var: `if(!in_array($_GET['page'], $pages_array) { die(); }`

Because you will probably need some other $_GET values/vars, i suggest that you use $_GET['page'] - for inclusion... You could later add mod rewrite to display pages as 'normal' urls... e.g.

www.yoursite.com/index.php?page=contact, could be rewritten to : www.yoursite.com/contact.html

Comment: can you tell me exactly where to put it because im new to php and dont know

Comment: In your index.php file. All other pages will be included inside index.php file.